# How to access an object's properties from the same object's (arrow) function

Tags: javascript, json, function, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In the normal function i can use this code

```
const person = {
  name: 'yaman',
  surname: 'katby',

  getFullName: function() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`
  }
}
```

What about arrow function by the way the code below not work

```
const person = {
  name: 'yaman',
  surname: 'katby',

  getFullName: () => `${name} ${surname}`
}
```

Comment: `getFullName: () => \`${person.name} ${person.surname}\`` - which you would do in both cases anyway

Answer (score 1):

The point of an arrow function is that it doesn't get its own `this`, it *closes over* the one where it was created.

In the situation you've shown, you probably wouldn't use an arrow function. But if you did, you'd have to refer to the object by the name of the constant (`person`), because you can't use `this`:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'yaman',
  surname: 'katby',

  getFullName: () => `${person.name} ${person.surname}`
};

console.log(person.getFullName());
```

Comment: why wouldn't you use the same `${person.name} ${person.surname}` in either case :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - The only reason I could see would be if you wanted to be able to use the function on another object.

Comment: fair enough - more complex case then :p